# Calculate Square root to decimal places in bash

Tags: bash, decimal-point, square-root

I am writing a simple bash script to calculate a square root to 3 decimal places by default but the user can set the number of places... Nothing complex, I just iterate from 1 to the lowest square root. Since my bash is still basic this is what I came up with.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

num=${1}
places=${2-3}
i=0

while [[ $(( i*i )) -lt ${num} ]]    // <= The problem should be here
do
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

echo ${i};
rem=$(( num % i ))
root="${i}."
for (( j=0; j<places; j++ ))
do
    rem=$((rem * 10))
    root="$root$((rem / i))"
    rem=$((rem % i))
done
echo ${root}
```

But due to some reason, it won't produce the correct result for a wide range of numbers
like `bashfile.sh 9 // will produce 3.000 but bashfile.sh 8 will return 3.666` kindly help, what is wrong with `while [[ ]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple, although not very efficient solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$1
prec=${2:-3}

for (( i=0; i < prec; ++i )); do let num*=100; done

for (( sqrt=0; sqrt*sqrt <= num; ++sqrt )); do :; done
let --sqrt

sqrt="${sqrt:0:-prec}.${sqrt: -prec}"
echo $sqrt
```

To answer your question ("what is wrong with `while [[ ]]`"), your comparison was slightly incorrect. Instead of `-lt` (ie, `<`) it should have been `<=`. And you needed to subtract 1 from `i` after the loop to get the correct whole part of the square root.

I couldn't make sense of the second part of your code that calculates decimal places. However, a simple solution is to instead pre-multiply the original number to get needed precision, which is what I've done above.

---

**UPDATE**

As @dash-o has pointed out if you are using bash, chances are you have either bc or awk installed, which are better suited for this:

```
num=$1
prec=${2:-3}

# using bc
echo "scale=$prec; sqrt($num)" | bc

# using awk
awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.${prec}f\n\", sqrt($num)}"
```

Comment: @AderemiDayo I noticed that too. It seems to be the 1st for-loop. If you are only using integers, you can try appending 0s instead of multiplication.

Comment: It is the 2nd for-loop, if you supply precision of `8` it will loop `num*10000000000000000` times, I don't even know where to start calculating the big O for that... lol

Comment: @AderemiDayo oh you are right. In that case instead of ++ increment, maybe try using binary search. For simplicity, you can assume `num` to be the upper bound and then keep slicing it in half until you get the result.

Answer (score 3):

The above code try to evaluate the sqrt with decimal in few steps:

- Evaluate the integer part of N, store as I
- Evaluate the decimal part of R=N-I*I, by dividing R by I.

However, this is incorrect. The code assumes that the breaks N into = (I*I) + (D*I), however, the requirement is to find N = (D+I)*(D+I) = D*D + I*I + 2*(D+I)

Two possible alternatives:

- Multiple the number by 10^(PREC*2), take the sqrt as integer, then print the number with the last PREC digits after a decimal point.
- Escape to to a tool capable of decimal numbers (awk, bc or dc)
- Implement the decimal calculation as inary search

Implementing option #1:

```
PREC=3   # Precision
V=123456  # input
for ((i=1 ; i<=PREC ; i++ )) ; do
  V=V*100
done
# Loop for matching i as above
```